# SQL Server table in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I connected SQL server database with Oracle SQL Developer 3.2.10.09, everything looks good except i can only browse data, i cannot change data in tables cannot insert new or delete rows. Query is also disabled (i got message: Query Builder is not supported for this connection type.) I used Third Party JDBC Drivers - jtds-1.2.6.jar as my connection to SQL server. Is there a way to change data in tables?

Answer (score 0):

It helped me to rollback to Oracle SQL Developer v.3.1.06.82
That Query Builder supports MS SQL Server tables

Answer (score -4):

I just use SQL Server Management Studio. You see.. when you buy a complete STACK of software, it comes with tools for writing SQL. Don't worry, if you're too cheap to buy $49/developer's edition of SQL Server, you can still get SSMS for free.

Comment: There is no option for me to use SQL Server Management Studio for some other reasons. I just want to know is there any way to edit rows (on sql server table) from Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: "FREE" it runs on Windows only. Did you know?

Comment: Insulting comments like this don't belong on SO.